# pass complex json as shortcode parameter

Tags: shortcode, json

I need to pass complex json with nested array of object as shortcode parameter.

For example I need to pass something like this:

```
{
   "a":"va",
   "b":{
      "b1":"vb1",
      "b2":[
         {
            "kb2":"vb2"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

So I tried to set the shortcode in this way:

```
[my_shortcode parameters='{"a": "va", "b": {"b1": "vb1", "b2": [{"kb2": "vb2"}]}}']
```

The problem seems to be related to array (square brackets) indeed this other example works:

```
[my_shortcode parameters='{"a": "va", "b": {"b1": "vb1"}}']
```

Here is how parameters are handled in shorcode:

```
function myshortcodehandler($atts){        
    $arrparameters = json_decode($atts["parameters"], true);
    ob_start(); 
    ?>        
    <pre><?php echo json_encode($arrparameters); ?></pre>        
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

If json includes some nested array the output show only some brackets. So, what is the right way to pass complex json as shortcode parameter?

I've already red this documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Square_Brackets

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like you're _really_ stretching what shortcodes are supposed to be used for. Why do you need such a complex parameter? Are users going to be typing these values in?

Comment: the solution is really quite dependent on how this is being implemented - where does the JSON come from?

Comment: The shortcode needs complex configuration and will be generated automatically. Users will just copy and paste the shortcode where they want.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a better solution, but [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) seems to do the job.

Instead of json I could pass json_decoded and then serialized parameters.

For example

```
$jsonval = json_decode('{"foo": "bar"}');
$serialized = serialize($jsonval);
```

Shortcode will be something like:

```
[myshortcode parameters='O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:8:"foo";s:3:"bar";}']
```

At this point I can handle parameters unserializing them:

```
function myshortcodehandler($atts){        
    $arrparameters = (array) unserialize($atts["parameters"]);
    ...
```

Seems to work also with array in json.